# Is my foreign key usage correct? Or do I need a different query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I will create three tables. These tables belong to a category name. The 'Department' category linked to the 'Company' category and the 'Department_Unit' category linked to the 'Department' category. The user will first select Company, then select department, then department_unit. Do you think the query I wrote below is correct? Or do I need to write a different and better query?
thankyou very much.

```
create_table_company= '''CREATE TABLE company(
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
); '''

create_table_department = '''CREATE TABLE department (
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
company_id BIGINT, 
FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES COMPANY(id)); '''

create_table_department_unit = '''CREATE TABLE department_unit(
ID SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY , 
NAME VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
department_id BIGINT,
FOREIGN KEY(department_id) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(id)); '''
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: I'm afraid in terms of performance. if I save other table foreign keys in the last table. I will be querying on a single table. However, in this way, I will run queries in 3 tables at the same time.I couldn't understand which one was right

Comment: One slight adjustment is advisable (imho). All your IDs are defined as serial. Serial is a shortcut for defining the column as an *integer*, create an integer sequence and make that sequence the default. Your FKs are defined as *bigint*. It is not that that setup is unworkable or has errors. However, consistency  is important. I would change the IDs to Bigserial or or the FK to integer. Even better,if you are on v10 or higher, change the IDs to a [Generated as Identity](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/#comment-248607) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data model looks fine.

Don't be worried that you have to join three tables whenever you need the company name that belongs to a department unit: databases are optimized to deal with such joins. In the case of an OLTP workload (you always select only a few rows from a table), this can be handled very efficiently with *nested loop joins*.

The only thing that is missing from your schema are two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON department (company_id);
CREATE INDEX ON department_unit (department_id);
```

These indexes are needed

- to make such nested loop joins efficient, for example if you are searching for all units that belong to a department
- to make deletes or key updates efficient, which have to search the referencing table to [verify that the foreign key constraint is still satisfied](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/)